# How to populate xsi type value as a parameter?

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is my original XSL template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:n="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:ns1="http://webservice_product/helloworld"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:sayHello">
  <ns1:sayHello xsi:type="ns698:Product" xmlns:ns698="urn:objects.prodcuts.com">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </ns1:sayHello>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In above xsl, i would like to parametrize xsi:type="ns698:Product" value. Like below-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:n="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:ns1="http://webservice_product/helloworld"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<xsl:variable name="name" select='"Product"' />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:sayHello">
  <ns1:sayHello xsi:type="ns698:$name" xmlns:ns698="urn:objects.prodcuts.com">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </ns1:sayHello>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this is not working. I tried hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<ns1:sayHello xsi:type="ns698:{$name}" xmlns:ns698="urn:objects.prodcuts.com">
```

Or

```
<xsl:variable name="name" select='"ns698:Product"' />
```

..

```
<ns1:sayHello xsi:type="{$name}" xmlns:ns698="urn:objects.prodcuts.com">
```